# Use an instance inside an anonymous class

Tags: java, arraylist, inner-classes, anonymous

I tried to use an instance of a anonymous class inside it when it's defined, but there were multiple errors given by IDE. I commented the question below. Is it a completely wrong way of using anonymous class, or is this because I wrote something incorrect? Thanks in advance!

```
  zoo = new ArrayList <AbstractCat>();
  AbstractCat cat = new AbstractCat (){//trying to create an anonymous class and add the instance cat to the ArrayList 
          zoo.add(this); //this line has multiple errors, I tried add(cat) but didn't work
          .....
          // override the methods in AbstractCat
```

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Wait a second.  Are you trying to create an instance of an `AbstractCat` and place it into a collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read your question in a different manner, it seems that you're trying to take the instance of `AbstractCat` that you've created, and add it to your `zoo` list.

Well...you can't do it in the manner you're attempting to from within the anonymous class.  You *might* be able to, but I'd **strongly** discourage it.

Instead, it'd be simpler for you to place the instance of the anonymous class that you hold into the list instead.

```
AbstractCat cat = new AbstractCat() {
    // impl
}

zoo.add(cat);
```

Comment: Thanks mate and yes that's what I am trying to do--create an instance of an AbstractCat and add it to a collection. Is there a way of doing this so that it is added to the list before the implementations of the methods in AbstractCat?

Comment: I don't think so.  It doesn't make sense to use an object that hasn't been instantiated yet.

Comment: but then how do we instantiate an abstract class, add it to a collection and then execute the methods? I mean is it possible to add it to list before running its methods? Sorry I am a bit confused..

Comment: I think you're getting a bit mixed up here.  You're only defining the anonymous class, and then you're instantiating it.  You haven't invoked any of it methods yet.  You can call methods on that instance later if you want to.

Comment: Ah Thank you! I think I get it. `AbstractCat cat = new AbstractCat(){..}` is defining the anonymous class right? In the {} I put in methods. And then after {} I can zoo.add(cat), following by call cat.run(); for example, that's invoke its method?

Comment: Yep.  Now you're getting it.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't do that, you need to execute `zoo.add(cat)` after you define the anonymous class.